# Sequelize null value in column violates not-null constraint

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm getting this error when trying to associate a like to a post.

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: null value in column
>   "userId" violates not-null constraint

Now the following code gets the post id and user id ok, i did a `console log`. What could i be doing wrong ?

**routes/posts.js**

```
router.post('/:userId/like/:postId', (req, res)=> {
    models.Post.findOne({
      where:{
          id: req.params.postId
      }
    })
    .then( (like) => {
        if(like){
            models.Likes.create({
                where:{
                    userId: req.params.userId,
                    postId: req.params.postId
                },
                like:true

            }).then( (result) => {
                res.status(200).send({
                    message: 'You have like this post',
                    like: result
                })
            })
        }
    }).catch( (err) => {
        res.status(401).send({
            message: "Something went wrong",
            err: err
        })
    })

})
```

here is the **likes migration**

```
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Likes', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      like: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN
      },
      userId: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'Users',
          key: 'id'
        }
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Likes');
  }
};
```

**Posts migration**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Posts', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      post_content: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      userId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'Users',
          key: 'id'
        }
      },
      username: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Posts');
  }
};
```

**Like model**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const Like = sequelize.define('Likes', {
    like:{
      type:DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull:true
    }
  }, {});
    Like.associate = function(models) {
        Like.belongsTo(models.User, {
          onDelete: "CASCADE",
          sourceKey: 'userId'

        })
        Like.belongsTo(models.Post, {
          onDelete: "CASCADE",
          sourceKey: 'likeId'

        })
    }
  return Like;
}
```

**Post.model**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Post = sequelize.define('Post', {
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    post_content: DataTypes.STRING,
    username:  DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  Post.associate = function(models) {
    Post.belongsTo(models.User, {  foreignKey: 'userId',  targetKey: 'id' });
    Post.hasMany(models.Likes, {  foreignKey: 'postId',  sourceKey: 'id' });
  };
  return Post;
};
```

extra

*add_postId_to_likes*

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
     return queryInterface.addColumn(
      'Likes',
      'postId',
      {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true,
        references: {
          model: 'Posts',
          key: 'id',

        }
      }
    )
  },

  down: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
     return queryInterface.removeColumn(
     'Likes',
     'postId'
   )
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your create call in resolver you are not giving it the necessary values, you have a where clause but not actually giving it the value for required userId.. looks like the only value in your model is the Boolean you are setting

Comment: I'm sorry greg i really don't understand, what you mean. because this `router.post('/:userId/like/:postId')` gets the user id and post id, i can see it works fine retrieving the data

Comment: what should i do instead ? how would i rewrite this to make it work, so it will attach a like to a post ?

Comment: Does your like table have columns called userID and likeID? You have them in your association but not in the model column list.. The only value you are setting in your Likes model is like: true, whatever you are doing in that where clause is not setting those values in the model, The error says that column userId is mandatory so you need to set it, I guess I am not sure why those columns are not listed in your model..

Comment: I don’t understand why you have a where clause in your create call for the like

Comment: because their defined in the migrations :( this is so confusing let me see what i can do. i will provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I just used `body` instead of `params` for the `postId`.

```
router.post('/like', (req, res)=> {

    models.Likes.create({
        postId: req.body.postId,
        userId:  req.user.id,
        like:true
    }).then( (result) => {
        res.status(200).send({
            message: 'You have like this post',
            like: result
        });
    }).catch( (err) => {
        res.status(401).send({
            message: "Something went wrong",
            err: err
        })
    })

})
```

change my like model to this, i was using sourceKey instead of **foreign keys**

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const Like = sequelize.define('Likes', {
    like:{
      type:DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull:true
    },
    // userId: {
    //   type: sequelize.INTEGER,
    //   references: {
    //     model: 'Users',
    //     key: 'id'
    //   }
    // },
  }, {});
    Like.associate = function(models) {
        Like.belongsTo(models.User, {
          onDelete: "CASCADE",
          foreignKey: 'userId'

        })
        Like.belongsTo(models.Post, {
          onDelete: "CASCADE",
          foreignKey: 'likeId'

        })
    }
  return Like;
}
```

So now i can like a post, and it will attach the `postId` along with the `usersId` on the likes table.

like this

[image]